# how to change color theme in materializecss

Tags: css, node.js, materialize

I have created nodejs project. Here is **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "materializecssdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Use of material design components",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "node-sass ./scss/theme.scss ./css/materialize-theme.css",
    "start": "lite-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Sunil Kumar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

I just want to change the colour of my app from its default colour to blue. So I have created **theme.scss** file and using **node-sass** module trying to generate CSS file. Here is my **theme.scss**

```
$primary-color: color("blue", "lighten-2") !default;
@import "../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize";
```

but this is showing

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "D:/SK/Study/MaterializeCSSDemo/node_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/_variables.scss",
  "line": 39,
  "column": 23,
  "message": "argument `$color` of `lighten($color, $amount)` must be a color\n\nBacktrace:\n\tnode_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/_variables.scss:39, in function `lighten`\n\tnode_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/_variables.scss:39",
  "formatted": "Error: argument `$color` of `lighten($color, $amount)` must be a color\n\n       Backtrace:\n       \tnode_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/_variables.scss:39, in function `lighten`\n       \tnode_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/_variables.scss:39\n        on line 39 of node_modules/materialize-css/sass/components/_variables.scss\n>> $primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;\n   ----------------------^\n"
}
```

is there any simple and clean way to make modifications to the theme? On the documentation page, it is saying by changing the **_variables.scss** file directely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$primary-color: lighten(blue, 2) !default;
```

Args passed to function should be a color and number. Not a string.

And there is no color function in scss.
You can create color using other function like hsl or rgb.
Check full list of scss functions [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html)

Answer (score 7):

Materialize comes with a [color palette](https://materializecss.com/color.html#palette) based on the material design base colors.

I recommend you to use these to set theme colors, to follow the Material Design [color system](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html).

To be able to do so, you have to import the file which defines these colors first, then set your theme color variables, then import the rest of materialize files. Not sure about our npm setup, but in [Rails with materialize-sass](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass) it works like this:

```
@import "materialize/components/color-variables";
$primary-color: color("blue", "lighten-2") !default;
$secondary-color: color("yellow", "base") !default;
@import 'materialize';
```

Comment: thks it works for me. You have to import `@import "materialize/components/color-variables";` before setting variables.